# How to create parallel loops

Tags: parallelization

My knowledge in parallel computing is very limited. I tried to figure out how to proceed using the mathematica help but did not really find what I needed. The programme looks as shown below. There are several loops, but what I would like is to parallelize the big loop (the one defined on r). I would be grateful if you had suggestions. Thanks a lot. Laurent

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"];
    kmax = 10000;
    m1 = 10.19357; s1 = 0.3022616; m2 = 11.795; s2 = s1;

    For[r = -0.99999999999, r <= 0.99999999999, r = r+0.09999999999,
     Clear[data];
     SeedRandom[1234];
     S = {{s1^2,r*s1*s2},{r*s1*s2,s2^2}};
     data = Sort[RandomVariate[LogMultinormalDistribution[{m1, m2}, S],kmax]];
     productivity = Table[data[[k]][[1]], {k, 1, kmax}];
     wagemin = Min[productivity];
     wagemax = Max[productivity];
     gamma = Table[data[[k]][[2]], {k, 1, kmax}];
     elasticity = Table[0.4/(wagemax - wagemin)*data[[k]][[1]] + 0.1 -
       0.4*wagemin/(wagemax - wagemin), {k, 1, kmax}];
     taxmax[r] = 0;

     For[tP = 0, tP < 1, tP = tP + 0.001,
     For[tC = 0, tC < tP, tC = tC + 0.001,
     Clear[wtilde];
     wtilde[g_, e_] := (((1 + e) g)/((1 - tC)^(1 + e) - (1 - tP)^(1+e)))^(1/(1 + e));
     For[k = 1, k <= kmax, k = k + 1,
       thresholds[k] =wtilde[gamma[[k]], elasticity[[k]]];];
     For[k = 1, k <= kmax, k = k + 1,
     If[productivity[[k]] <= thresholds[k], winf[k] = productivity[[k]], winf[k] = 0];
     If[productivity[[k]] <= thresholds[k], einf[k] = elasticity[[k]], einf[k] = 1];
     If[productivity[[k]] > thresholds[k], wmax[k] = productivity[[k]], wmax[k] = 0];
     If[productivity[[k]] > thresholds[k], emax[k] = elasticity[[k]], emax[k] = 1];];
     tax = tP*Sum[(1 - tP)^einf[k]*winf[k]^(1 + einf[k]), {k, 1, kmax}] +
       tC*Sum[(1 - tC)^emax[k]*wmax[k]^(1 + emax[k]), {k, 1, kmax}];
     gdp = Sum[(1 - tP)^einf[k]*winf[k]^(1 + einf[k]), {k, 1, kmax}] + 
       Sum[(1 - tC)^emax[k]*wmax[k]^(1 + emax[k]), {k, 1, kmax}];

      If[tax >= taxmax[r], taxmax[r] = tax; tPopt[r] = tP; tCopt[r] = tC;];
      ] (* End loop tC *);
      ] (* End loop tP*);

   Print["r =", r, " Optimum: tP =", tPopt[r], "; tC=", tCopt[r]];
```

Comment: Asking us to fix/rewrite your specific code for you won't probably be well received here, and may be closed as too localized. Perhaps you could reduce your example to a much simpler independent minimal working case, show us what you tried on that one, indicate why it didn't work, and then you will receive much better feedback.

Comment: One off-topic tip, `For` is not as optimized as `Do` and is (significantly) slower. I recommend using [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) instead. (e.g. `Do[ (*blah blah*), {r, -0.99999999999, 0.99999999999, 0.09999999999} ]` and so on)

Comment: Try to rewrite your For loops into Map or Table statements. See the documentation on Map/Table for some examples. This is the hard part, but it is worth learning. Once you do this, you can replace them with ParallelMap or ParallelTable.

Comment: As a second note, your code is in one giant block. This is bad. You should try to define some functions so that your code is broken up into smaller parts.

Comment: You can gain at least a factor of two in speed, and perhaps much more, by writing the inner loop more efficiently.  Concentrate of efficient code first, and worry about parallelization afterword, if you still need it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime for this code as written but with `kmax` reduced to `1000` and the `tP` and `tC` increments increased to `0.1`, is `37 sec` (`AbsoluteTiming`) on my four-processor PC after correcting a typo in the final line, a missing `]`.  (Without those parameter changes, runtime would be about `100000` times longer.)

Runtime can be reduced an order of magnitude by focusing on the two innermost `For` loops (i.e., `For[k = 1, k <= kmax, k = k + 1, ...]`) and `Sum`s:

- The `Sum`s comprising `tax` and `gdp` are computed twice but need be computed only once.
- When `winf` or `wmax` is zero, the corresponding term in the corresponding sum also is zero and need not be calculated.
- `MapThread` is faster than `For` in this instance.

With these changes, runtime decreases to `12 sec`.  The outer loops also can be optimized,

- Eliminate `Sort`, which is unnecessary.
- Replace `For`-loops by `Do`-loops.
- Replace `Table` by `Transpose` to compute `productivity` and `gamma`.
- Replace `Table` by `Map` to compute `elasticity`

compressing the code to

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
kmax = 1000; m1 = 10.19357; s1 = 0.3022616; m2 = 11.795; s2 = s1;

Do[
  taxmax = 0; SeedRandom[1234];
  S = {{s1^2, r*s1*s2}, {r*s1*s2, s2^2}};
  {productivity, gamma} = RandomVariate[LogMultinormalDistribution[{m1, m2}, S], kmax] 
    // Transpose;
  wagemin = Min[productivity]; wagemax = Max[productivity];
  elasticity = Map[(0.4/(wagemax - wagemin)*(# - wagemin) + 0.1) &, productivity];

  Do[
    wtilde[g_, e_] := (((1 + e) g)/((1 - tC)^(1 + e) - (1 - tP)^(1 + e)))^(1/(1 + e));
    thresholds = MapThread[wtilde, {gamma, elasticity}];
    sum1 = MapThread[If[#1 <= #2, (1 - tP)^#3*#1^(1 + #3), 0] &, 
      {productivity, thresholds, elasticity}] // Total;
    sum2 = MapThread[If[#1 > #2, (1 - tC)^#3*#1^(1 + #3), 0] &, 
      {productivity, thresholds, elasticity}] // Total;
    tax = tP*sum1 + tC*sum2; gdp = sum1 + sum2;
    If[tax >= taxmax, taxmax = tax; tPopt = tP; tCopt = tC;], 
  {tP, 0, 1 - 0.0001, 0.1}, {tC, 0, tP - 0.0001, 0.1}]

  Print["r =", r, " Optimum: tP =", tPopt, "; tC=", tCopt],
{r, -0.99999999999, 0.99999999999, 0.09999999999}]
```

although doing so saves negligible time.  Finally, simply replacing  the outermost `Do` by `ParallelDo` reduces runtime of this reduced problem to `4 sec`, an overall reduction of a factor of ten.

Note that this particular problem does not require returning results from the subordinate kernels to the master kernel.  To do so would require use of `SetSharedVariable`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This was very useful and all the provided details helped me better understand how to write my code in a more efficient way.